# Generate OLAP Analytic Workspaces PLSQL without using Quick DDL function on SQL Developer

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, olap, olap-cube

I am currently using SQL developer and OLAPTRAIN Schema to learn about OLAP, and I was able to create the Analytic Workspace, 'SALESTRACK'. I know there is a way to right-click on the AW, select quick DDL, and save as PLSQL to a worksheet or save as XML to Clipboard. However, I am looking for the script that I can type in the SQL Worksheet or SQL Plus to generate the AW DDL/XML. I have got any luck from my research and I hope someone could shed some light on it. Thank you.

Comment: what do you want your script to do? your script could generate PL/SQL dynamically to mirror what the sqldev feature is doing for example.

Comment: I want the script to create the AW and the OLAP objects that I had in the SALESTRACK AW. I was able to get the DDL from the quick DDL, but I guess I am asking the command or script behind quick DDL for generating the whole AW DDL/XML.